# Paypal Test subscribe button

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions, recurring-billing

I need to test a subscribe button using the sandbox provided by paypal. I have a button with the following code:

```
  <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
  <input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/es_XC/i/btn/x-click-but6.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
   <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="cda.1_1350317871_biz@mymail.es"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Anuncio Premium"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="SS-001"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="3.00"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="D"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php print $user->uid; ?>">
```

As you can see I set t3=D and p3=1 in order to force paypal to send recurring payments every minute as paypal specifices here: 
https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_Sandbox_UserGuide/testing_recurringpayments.html

Everything works fine. I receive the first pay, its corresponding IPN and in my test account a recurring payment profile is created. But there is no more recurring payments received so my queston is if am I doing anything wrong. I'd like to receive recurring payments in short periods of time so I haven't to wait 1 day to test my web.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this feature hasn't worked for quite some time and they're aware of it, but it hasn't been high priority enough to get it fixed.

If you need to test IPN's based on recurring payments I would recommend setting up a simple HTML form with the action set to your IPN listener URL, and then add a bunch of hidden fields that match the names and values of what you'd expect to get from IPN.

This way you can submit directly to your IPN listener in a browser and see errors on screen.  This is also helpful for troubleshooting.

Keep in mind that when doing this the IPN verification system will fail because the data is not coming from the actual PayPal system.  You can handle this accordingly for testing purposes, though.